# WHERE clause error

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm trying to display a specific value in the data base in an HTML table. The statement is like this:(this is just an example)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_trainings WHERE tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'";
```

My problem is I have this statement(joined tables):

```
$sql="SELECT 
tbl_info.id, 
tbl_info.firstname, 
tbl_info.middlename, 
tbl_info.lastname, 
tbl_trainings.id,
tbl_trainings.training,
tbl_trainings.info_id
  FROM tbl_info, tbl_trainings
  WHERE tbl_info.id = info_id 
  ORDER BY tbl_info.id";
```

I'm trying to insert the `WHERE tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'` in the statement like this:

```
$sql="SELECT 
tbl_info.id, 
tbl_info.firstname, 
tbl_info.middlename, 
tbl_info.lastname, 
tbl_trainings.id,
tbl_trainings.training,
tbl_trainings.info_id
  FROM tbl_info, tbl_trainings
  WHERE tbl_info.id = info_id, tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'
  ORDER BY tbl_info.id";
```

But I got error. The error is:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\CLphpTest\meatproc.php

Can anyone please help me to correct this?
(I'm sorry. still a noob)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way you should not use `mysql_` for pro programms use `mysqli_` or better `PDO`.

Comment: And **don't** use http://w3schools.com, as the information is outdated & misleading. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: You are missing an AND instead of comma

  WHERE tbl_info.id = info_id AND tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'

Answer (score 4):

add `AND/OR` if you have multiple conditions in the query, eg

```
WHERE tbl_info.id = info_id AND
      tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'
```

as a side not, use the newer syntax of join,

```
SELECT  tbl_info.id,
        tbl_info.firstname,
        tbl_info.middlename,
        tbl_info.lastname,
        tbl_trainings.id,
        tbl_trainings.training,
        tbl_trainings.info_id
FROM    tbl_info
        INNER JOIN tbl_trainings
            ON tbl_info.id = tbl_trainings.info_id
WHERE   tbl_trainings.training = 'Meat Processing'
ORDER   BY tbl_info.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Should be "WHERE tbl_info.id = info_id AND tbl_trainings.training='Meat Processing'
```